# Converting the date in java for plotting a graph

Tags: java, date

my problem is with RegularTimePeriod... 
i have the date in the datebase saved as Date type
i'm trying to retrieve them and process them through RegularTimePeriod but it keeps giving me null... 
the code is

```
    RegularTimePeriod t = new Day();
    t = t.createInstance(Date.class, resultado.getData(), TimeZone.getDefault());
```

but i'm always getting it as empty value when i debug it, can anyone tell me a way to get it work please.

Comment: The Date and Time capabilities built into Java are notoriously horrible. I would suggest you use the JodaTime library for doing _anything_ with dates or times. It makes the sorts of things you are trying to do almost fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source code of this function

```
public static RegularTimePeriod createInstance(Class c, 
                        Date millisecond, TimeZone zone) {
    RegularTimePeriod result = null;
    try {
        Constructor constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor(
                    new Class[] { Date.class, TimeZone.class });
        result = (RegularTimePeriod) constructor.newInstance(
                    new Object[] { millisecond, zone });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do nothing, so null is returned
    }
    return result;
}
```

it expects subclass of `RegularTimePeriod`, but you use it with `Date` which is not what required.

I assume you should do something like

t = t.createInstance(**Day**.class, resultado.getData(), TimeZone.getDefault());

Comment: thank you so much for the tip , i shall try it now and will update